# How to evaluate string width and convert to CGFloat (swift)

Tags: swift

i have found these code but seems it doesn't work.

```
 func evaluateStringWidth (textToEvaluate: String) -> CGFloat{
    letfont = NSFont.userFontOfSize(NSFont.systemFontSize())
    let attributes = NSDictionary(object: font!, forKey:NSFontAttributeName)
    let sizeOfText = textToEvaluate.sizeWithAttributes((attributes as! [String : AnyObject]))
    return sizeOfText.width
}
```

Comment: Please describe your issue more specifically. What "it doesn't work" mean? It does not compile? It causes runtime errors? Or it returns something unexpected? And you need to specify what platform you are using. The code you have shown is for OS X (macOS). Are you sure you are testing your code on OS X?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what you mean.
So, I answered by guesswork.

```
func evaluateStringWidth (textToEvaluate: String) -> CGFloat {
    let maxSize = self.view.frame.size //set your view or label size
    let attributesDictionary = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0)] //set your font object
    let textSize = NSString(string: textToEvaluate).boundingRectWithSize(maxSize, options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributesDictionary, context: nil)

    return textSize.width
}
```